# Present perfect + definite time : exceptions

Tags: present-perfect

Is it ok to use the present perfect with a definite time if it's used with may or could ?

Examples :

- I may have drunk too much yesterday night
- I could have done it last month but I was too lazy for that.

If yes what are the other exceptions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These sentences are both entirely acceptable. However, neither contains a present perfect: in both the *have + PastParticiple* is not a 'true' perfect construction but a 'past marker' required by the peculiarities of modal verbs.

This is tricky. Let's start with a modal 'true' present perfect:

> A. John may have finished the report already.

This may be paraphrased as "It is possible that John **has finished** the report already". Both clauses occupy the same timeframe, the present: *may* makes a present possibility evaluation of a proposition (*John has finished the report, the report is complete*) representing a present state arising out of the past eventuality—which is exactly what the present perfect expresses.

> B. I may have drunk too much yesterday night.

This will not bear the same sort of paraphrase as A ("It is possible that I have drunk too much last night")—not only because it is ungrammatical (a present perfect will not marry with a temporal expression which does not include the present) but also because there is a contrast of timeframes: *may* makes a present possibility evaluation of a proposition about the past: (*I **drank** too much last night*). The pseudo-perfect construction *have drunk* is brought in to express the temporal contrast, to mark *DRINK* explicitly as past-tensed.

> C. I could have done it last month but I was too lazy for that.

In this case, the past-tense form of *can* is employed to express contrafactuality. If this sentence were cast in the present tense, *could* would be used by itself:

> C1. I could do it now, but I am too lazy for that.

You can backshift this into the past tense by replacing *am* with *was*. But what do you do with *could*?  You've already so to speak "used up" the past-tense form to express contrafactuality; so to mark this clause as past-tensed you have to bring in outside help: again, the pseudo-perfect *have done* is a 'past marker'.

Answer (score 0):

The Present Perfect is used with "*can*", "*may*", "*must*", etc. to indicate a past ability, probability, likelihood.

Examples:

> He must have heard me last night - today he spoke about it.
>   We may have been too hasty last Tuesday in letting the dogs out.
>   What can he have done last spring to deserve his dismissal?

Comment: So these 3 verbs are the only exceptions ?

Comment: I don't consider them exceptions.  How else would you form a past likelihood statement?  In Present you say "you *must be* hungry".  How do you say it about yesterday night?  Here is the form: "you must *have been* hungry yesterday night."  And not only those three. You found 'could'; add to those 'should', 'would'... Probably others. (I'm too lazy to look for those on the web for you, sorry)

Comment: It can't be **present** perfect: the *HAVE* component, which in a perfect bears the tense, is an infinitive here and has no tense.

Comment: Yes, certainly.  Looks like one, don't it though?

Comment: I know it's not correct but I would form the past like this : I could did it last month / I may drank too much last night.

Comment: :-)  If you know it's not correct, then why would you do it?

Comment: Because the past simple is the tense I would use when there is a definite time, so it seems more logic to me but sometimes languages are not logic !